# How do you separate inputs on the zoom H4n so you can adjust each mic level 

Tags: zoom, zoom-h4n, lavalier, production-audio

Hey everyone! Recently I was on a shoot with two lavs and one shotgun. The shotgun mic was plugged straight into the camera that we had on set and the lav receivers were plugged into mic inputs 1 and 2. Now here's where my question come's in. One lady was yelling and the other wasn't but I could only set the mic level for both inputs. Does anyone know how to manually adjust the mic level on each input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to update your firmware first, if you haven't already done so:
http://www.zoom.co.jp/downloads/h4n/software/

Then you just go to: Menu / Input / Turn OFF 1/2 Link (http://www.hv20.com/showthread.php?43895-Zoom-h4n)

Once linking is turned off, all you need to do is to click on the buttons (1) or (2) under the MIC-button, and just adjust the Rec Level.